# Replicate Error in Azure Locally

Tags: testing, azure, replication

I'm currently working on a project. The project has a web role and a worker role. Whenever a new instance of the project is deployed to windows azure, I would notice that the web role would start normally, however, the worker role would throw and error. It will stay "recycling". Then, it would say that there was a type initialization exception.

However, when I debug the project on my local machine I do not experience this error. Is there a way for me to replicate the project locally, or at least view the stack trace of the error?

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying from within Visual Studio, enable IntelliTrace during the publish wizard. Once the role is unhealthy, you can download the IntelliTrace logs and see the stack of the exception.
I am guessing that a DLL is not being copied with the deployment.